# jQuery selector for all inputs apart from those within a DIV

Tags: jquery

I've tried so many selectors but just can't get this to work

Here is what I have:

```js
$(':input').filter(':not(#CLASSES).children()')
```

What can I try next?

Comment: not sure where you learned about `.children()` is CSS selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use not with a selector instead of filter?

```js
$(":input").not("#foo :input").css("background-color","green")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tb1" />
<input id="tb2" />
<div id="foo">
  <input id="tb3" />
  <input id="tb4" />
</div>
<input id="tb5" />
<input id="tb6" />
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant thank you so much...

$(':input').not('#CLASSES :input').not('#APPLICATIONS :input')

I have 2 divs with stuff I need to ignore

Comment: could be one not `.not('#foo input, #bar input')`